# Better ways to modify string with multiple methods?

Tags: javascript

In the string `str` I am making the string lower case and capitalizing the first word. Is there a better way to modify strings then what I did? I tried doing `return str.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toUpperCase();`, however, all this does is return the letter `H`. Is there a better way to chain methods onto a variable containing a string?

```js
let str = `HOW ARE YOU DOING TODAY?`

function capitalize() {

  str1 = str.toLowerCase()

  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str1.slice(1);
}

console.log(capitalize());  /// -> How are you doing today?
```

Comment: Anything wrong with `str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str1.slice(1)` in particular?

Comment: simply use css `text-transform: capitalize;` ?

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do something along the lines of   str.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toUpperCase()   rather then dissecting the sentence into parts.

Comment: either of the comments above do what you are asking without dissecting the sentence into parts.

Comment: I am having to select the first character of the string and then slice the remaining part of the sentence and add them together. I was trying to ask if you could modify the string with methods without having to concatenate the 'divided parts' together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concept and the implementation approach is correct.
You can use the template literals and arrow functions, to make the code more concise

```
const capitalize = (str) =>  `${str.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`;
```

Comment: Template literals in this particular case make the expression several characters **longer**.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple elegant solution:

```js
let str = "HOW ARE YOU DOING TODAY?";

function capitalize(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

console.log(capitalize(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = `HOW ARE YOU DOING TODAY?`

function capitalize(str) {

  return `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`;
}

console.log(capitalize(str));  /// -> How are you doing today?
```

Answer (score 0):

As strings are immutable in JS, you can't change them in place. You could instead consider using `.replace()` with a regular expression to obtain the first character (`.`) and the rest (`.+`) so that you can make the first character uppercase, and the rest lowercase:

```js
const capitalize = str =>
  str.toLowerCase().replace(/(.)(.+)/g, (_, f, r) => f.toUpperCase() + r);

console.log(capitalize("HOW ARE YOU DOING TODAY?"));
```

You could also consider using destructuring to obtain the first character and rest of the string like so:

```js
const capitalize = ([f="", ...r]) =>
  `${f.toUpperCase()}${r.join('').toLowerCase()}`;

console.log(capitalize(""));
```